# getting Windows Identity Foundation "Developer Training Kit" examples to work

Tags: visual-studio, https, wif, geneva-server

I downloaded the "Developer Training Kit" for Windows Identity Foundation and installed it on a newly set up Windows Server 2008 R2 virtual machine.  When I open up the example solutions and press F5 to run them, I get the following error:

"Unable to start debugging on the web server.  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

If I try to start the web page without debugging (Ctrl-F5), I get a "Connection was reset" error in the browser.  Nothing works!

The only thing unusual here is that I see that the addresses on the local machine begin with https instead of http as I am used to in my development environment.  Has anyone here been able to get these code samples to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this here:  [social.msdn.microsoft.com/...](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Geneva/thread/e98aac6a-5edc-4a29-927a-1774d6114404).

There is a bug in the installation script.  You have to open the script and make changes with a text editor.

To quote from the site linked above ( in case it disappears ), make the following change to SetupCertificates.cmd.  Replace

@if ("%IsWinClient%" == "true") (

ECHO Setting up SSL at port 443 using localhost certificate...

netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 appid={00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} certhash=%CERTHASH% clientcertnegotiation=enable

) else (

ECHO Importing server certificate and point HTTP.SYS at it...

httpcfg.exe set ssl -i 0.0.0.0:443 -f 2 -h %CERTHASH%

)

With

ECHO Setting up SSL at port 443 using localhost certificate...

netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 appid={00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} certhash=%CERTHASH% clientcertnegotiation=enable