# Using WIF in an Idp-Initiated SSO environment from MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif, saml-2.0

I have an MVC 4 application receiving SAML2 tokens from an initiating IdP. I can see the token as it arrives and I can decrypt it. However, I want to do this with WIF 3.5 and seem to be having problems with SAML Namespaces when I try to use the WSSecurityTokenSerializer as follows:

> System.Xml.XmlException was unhandled by user code
>     HResult=-2146232000
>     Message=Cannot read the token from the 'Response' element with the 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol' namespace for BinarySecretSecurityToken, with a '' ValueType. If this element is expected to be valid, ensure that security is configured to consume tokens with the name, namespace and value type specified.
>     Source=System.ServiceModel
>     LineNumber=0
>     LinePosition=0
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityTokenSerializer.ReadTokenCore(XmlReader reader, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver)
>          at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenSerializer.ReadToken(XmlReader reader, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver)
>          at SamlHandlingTests.SamlTests.TestMethod1() in g:\Projects\mytempesub\Solution\SamlHandlingTests\SamlTests.cs:line 112
>     InnerException:

I have seen a post here [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108564/problems-reading-authenticating-a-saml-assertion-in-net-using-wssecuritytokense) but the final resolution of doing things directly with XML doesn't suit me because I need to be able to run this up as a standard IdP-Initiated solution.

Therefore I have two questions:

1. Has anyone ever managed to overcome this error with WIF? (I don't need the WIF Extensions as I am only concerned with handling SAML2 tokens, not protocol.
2. To use WIF in an IdP-Initiated environment I understand requires no configuration, I have simply set authentication off and I check the incoming token. However, I would prefer to check the token in the full WIF pipeline but this then needs configuration. How can I configure WIF to function in this IdP-Initiated environment?

Many thanks

Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to deserialize the token you might consider instead using [Saml2SecurityTokenHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.saml2.saml2securitytokenhandler.aspx).

I would also ask, does your scenario require you to deserialize the token yourself? WIF integrates well with ASP.NET MVC applications so you might instead rely on the WIF to do this for you. See Eugenio's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621496/asp-net-mvc-2-and-authentication-using-wif-windows-identity-foundation).

Comment: it would have been easier if this were SP-Initiated rather than IdP-Initiated SSO. For this reason, the link to Eugenio's answer doesn't work in my scenario. However, your pointer to Saml2SecurityTokenHandler looks really useful. I will try it out